# What happens if bowler's steps get tangled?

Tags: rules, cricket

If the bowler's steps get tangled, during his run-up until the time before which he releases his delivery, then what is the procedure regarding it? In such a case of tangling of steps, the bowler might run-into the umpire, be swayed from his path away from the pitch, or simply fall straight onto the ground. I searched the laws but couldn't find any mention of this.

Has this ever happened before? And what is the official procedure for handling this situation? Is a no-ball given or a dead ball?

Comment: I would appreciate any explanation for the downvotes though. If there is anything unclear in the question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Law 20, *Dead ball* provides that

> 20.4.2 Either umpire shall call and signal Dead ball when
>
> ...
>
> 20.4.2.9 the ball does not leave the bowler’s hand for any reason other than an attempt to run out the non-striker under Law 41.16 (Non-striker leaving his/her ground early).

The umpire calls and signals dead ball. It does not count as a ball in the over, as provided by Law 17, *The over* saying

> 17.3.2 A ball delivered by the bowler shall not count as one of the 6 balls of the over
>
> 17.3.2.1 if it is called dead, or is to be considered dead, before the striker has had an opportunity to play it. See Law 20.6 (Dead ball; ball counting as one of over).

and the aforementioned Law 20, *Dead ball* reinforcing the statement that

> 20.6.1 When a ball which has been delivered is called dead or is to be considered dead then, ...
>
> 20.6.1.1 it will not count in the over if the striker has not had an opportunity to play it.

A bowler muffing their run-up is not common, but will typically only occur once or twice in a one day international innings, if at all.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you just said. The Law you referenced makes no mention of tangling of bowler's steps. (Besides, if the umpire calls and signals "no ball" why wouldn't it count as a ball in the over?)

Comment: Tangentially, a no ball is by definition not counted as one of the six balls in the over, and similarly a dead ball called prior to the striker being able to play it. See Law 17, *The over*. // I stated no ball in the original answer despite referring to a dead ball situation, error now corrected. // The law quoted in my answer is very clear: "for **any** reason" except attempting a run-out on the non-striker. I have ignored the statement "before which he releases his delivery" in your question because the bowler *won't bowl the ball at all* if the run-up is muffed.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you! But, has such a muffling of steps happened before? I don't watch much cricket so I am not sure. I couldn't find anything on youtube either.

Comment: As I said, muffing of any kind is not common in general. Maybe once or twice in an international match, or less. A bowler tripping over themselves? I've seen it a couple of times.

Comment: Aren't muffling/tangling/tripping all the same?

Comment: I use *muffing* to mean breaking up the run-up in any way at all.